# nothing happen on my telegeram bot

Tags: php-telegram-bot

i want to create a Telegram bot, i write this codes, and also i set the Webhook, this code return the Json response from telegram bot to itself, but i don`t know why it is not working..
any help and guide will be appreciated.

```
$token = 'my token';
// read incoming info and grab the chatID 
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$telegram = urldecode ($json);
$results = json_decode($telegram); 




// send reply
$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$token.'/sendMessage?chat_id=80853440&text='.$json;
 file_get_contents($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

GET Requests are limited. Try using curl for a POST request or write an array containing chat_id, ...
Then use

```
$arrayname["method"] = "sendMessage"; //Req method for example sendMessage
echo json_encode($arrayname);
```

Please read [Telegram Api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) and [php.net](https://php.net/) for more informations.